# Problem with _initStores() while saving from Magento configuration section

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I'm getting a 500 internal service error while trying to save any options from Magento's configuration menu (Magento v1.9.0.1).

Edit: removing the line `$this->_stores   = array();` removes the problem entirely. I'm currently trying to figure out why that's the case.

I've tracked the error down to the _initStores() method in Mage/Core/Model/App. Here's how I've marked up the method to see when PHP craps out:

```
protected function _initStores()
    {
        Mage::log('_initStores called', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_stores   = array();
        Mage::log('Stores set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_groups   = array();
        Mage::log('Groups set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_website  = null;
        Mage::log('Website set to null', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_websites = array();
        Mage::log('Websites set to blank array', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        Mage::log('Setting model website collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Website */
        $websiteCollection = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()
                ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Website::CACHE_TAG))
                ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('Setting model store group collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
        $groupCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->getCollection()
                ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group::CACHE_TAG))
                ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('Setting model store collection', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        /** @var $websiteCollection Mage_Core_Model_Store */
        $storeCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
            ->initCache($this->getCache(), 'app', array(Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG))
            ->setLoadDefault(true);
        Mage::log('_isSingleStore logic', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        $this->_isSingleStore = false;
        if ($this->_isSingleStoreAllowed) {
            $this->_isSingleStore = $storeCollection->count() < 3;
        }

        $websiteStores = array();
        $websiteGroups = array();
        $groupStores   = array();
        Mage::log('Before storeCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($storeCollection as $store) {
            /** @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
            Mage::log('Initconfigcache', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->initConfigCache();
            Mage::log('Setting website', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->setWebsite($websiteCollection->getItemById($store->getWebsiteId()));
            Mage::log('Setting group', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $store->setGroup($groupCollection->getItemById($store->getGroupId()));
            Mage::log('Setting place in _stores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $this->_stores[$store->getId()] = $store;
            $this->_stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
            Mage::log('Setting place in websitestores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $websiteStores[$store->getWebsiteId()][$store->getId()] = $store;
            Mage::log('Setting place in groupstores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
            $groupStores[$store->getGroupId()][$store->getId()] = $store;

            if (is_null($this->_store) && $store->getId()) {
                $this->_store = $store;
            }
        }
        Mage::log('Before groupCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
            /* @var $group Mage_Core_Model_Store_Group */
            if (!isset($groupStores[$group->getId()])) {
                $groupStores[$group->getId()] = array();
            }
            $group->setStores($groupStores[$group->getId()]);
            $group->setWebsite($websiteCollection->getItemById($group->getWebsiteId()));

            $websiteGroups[$group->getWebsiteId()][$group->getId()] = $group;

            $this->_groups[$group->getId()] = $group;
        }
        Mage::log('Before websiteCollection foreach', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
        foreach ($websiteCollection as $website) {
            /* @var $website Mage_Core_Model_Website */
            if (!isset($websiteGroups[$website->getId()])) {
                $websiteGroups[$website->getId()] = array();
            }
            if (!isset($websiteStores[$website->getId()])) {
                $websiteStores[$website->getId()] = array();
            }
            if ($website->getIsDefault()) {
                $this->_website = $website;
            }
            $website->setGroups($websiteGroups[$website->getId()]);
            $website->setStores($websiteStores[$website->getId()]);

            $this->_websites[$website->getId()] = $website;
            $this->_websites[$website->getCode()] = $website;
        }
        Mage::log('End of initstores', null, 'configsaveissue.log');
    }
```

According to my logs, this method runs completely before the saveAction() method is called on the ConfigController, then is called again but stops on the first line, printing only '_initStores called' to the log file.

Any ideas on why PHP would stop while setting $_stores to an empty array? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: maybe you run out of memory

Comment: That could be. The $_stores variable is huge when I log it on the second round. However, does it take a significant amount of memory to replace a large value with an empty array?

I also tried using unset($this->_stores); and $this->_stores = null; before the line that sets it to an empty array, but it had no effect.